# Limitar resultado que tiver a mesma ID

Tags: php, html

Olá! Criei 2 tabelas e fiz uma relação entre elas. No caso eu quero limitar a quantidade de um item se tiver o mesmo ID, exemplo:

> ```
> Hotel IBIS - São Paulo
> Hotel IBIS - Rio de Janeiro
> Hotel IBIS - Porto Alegre
> Hotel IBIS - Brasilia
> Hotel Plaza - São Paulo
> Hotel Plaza - Rio de Janeiro
> Hotel Plaza - Porto Alegre
> Hotel Plaza - Brasilia
> ```

Os estados fazem relação com o Hotel que é a tabela principal. Ai na minha página principal está mostrando todos hotéis de uma vez, e o que eu quero fazer é tipo mostrar 2 de cada assim:

> ```
> Hotel IBIS - São Paulo
> Hotel IBIS - Rio de Janeiro
> Hotel Plaza - São Paulo
> Hotel Plaza - Rio de Janeiro
> ```

Meu código:

```
 $sql = "select * from estados join hotel on estados.id_hotel = hotel.id order by estados.id DESC limit 5";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você utilizar o [group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Olá! Poderia me dá um exemplo de como fazer?

Comment: Olá,poderia mostrar a estrutura da tabela ? assim podemos executar as querys e te ajudar.

Comment: Olá! Editei e coloquei como está a estrutura do banco que fiz.

Comment: id da tabela Hotel é uma chave primária  ou todos os hotel BIS tem o mesmo id ?

Comment: Na tabela hotel tem 2 hoteis cadastrados que seria Hotel Ibis e a outra é Hotel Plaza. Ai na tabela Estados elas estão pegando o ID de uma delas.

Comment: O ideal é não usar o mesmo nome de colunas em duas tabelas. Por exemplo, vc tá usando "nome" nas duas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz alguns testes e algumas pesquisas, encontrei uma solução para esse caso.

```
/* Nessa primeira parte nós definimos algumas variáveis */
SET
  @num := 0,
  @type := 'estado';

SELECT
  `estado`,
  hotel
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    hotel.hotel AS hotel,
    estado,
    @num := IF(@type = `estado`, /* Aqui nós fizemos uma comparação com o valor de estado, caso a variável "type" seja igual ao valor do campo... */
    @num + 1, /* Soma o valor da variável */
    1) AS row_number, /* Caso contrário ele define como 1 e adiciona uma alias que utilizaremos mais à frente */
    @type := `estado` AS estado_name
  FROM
    estados
  LEFT JOIN
    hotel ON(hotel.id = estados.id_hotel)
  ORDER BY
    `estado`
) AS X
WHERE X
  .row_number <= 2 /* Aqui nós utilizamos o alias para verificar e retornar quantos valores de cada grupos nós queremos. */
LIMIT 4;
```

**Minha estrutura:**

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `estados`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `estados`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estados` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_hotel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `hotel`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hotel`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Utilizei como base o artigo [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/#select-the-top-n-rows-from-each-group), vale a pena a leitura.

**[Demonstração do Código](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7978a3/1)**

Comment: Vlw. Obrigado. Vou Estudar um pouco o código.